# If all the permutations of the letters of the word SMALL are listed in alphabetical order, in which position would SMALL appear?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If all the words (with or without meaning) having five letters, formed using the letters of the word $S$$M$$A$$L$$L$ and arranged in a dictionary, then find the position of the word $S$$M$$A$$L$$L$$?$

First of all, I am trying this question by arranging the letters of the word $S$$M$$A$$L$$L$ in the alphabetical order. So, after arranging the letters of the word $S$$M$$A$$L$$L$ in Alphabetical order, the word I am getting is $A$$L$$L$$M$$S$. Now using the letter $A$ the no. of words that can be formed is 4$!$$/$2$!$ which is equal to 12. Now I am facing problem in proceeding further with L, because there are 2 L's. So, please help me out to solve.

Comment: There are $5!/2!$ possible words with the division because of the two Ls.  Only a few come after SMALL: you could list them

Comment: Please help me out with the full solution.

Comment: SMLAL and SMLLA come later

Answer (score 2):

$SMALL$ can be arranged (with/without meaning) in $5!/2!$ ways, as there are $2 L's$.

To find its position, arrange and list them in alphabetical order:

1. With $A$ as beginning: $4!/2! = 12$ possibilities
2. With $L$ as beginning: $4! = 24$ possibilities
3. With $M$ as beginning: $4!/2! = 12$ possibilities
4. With $S$ as beginning, further check & list them alphabetically:

   - $SA$ will have: $3!/2! = 3$ possibilities
   - $SL$ will have: $3! = 6$ possibilities
   - $SM$ will be listed further and will be arranged alphabetically in the dictionary

     - $SMALL$ will eventually be the first word starting with $SMA$, and the ONLY possibility.

Therefore, position of $SMALL$ in the dictionary made only using the letters of $SMALL$ is adding them all up plus 1 (for position of $SMALL$):
$12 + 24 + 12 + 3 + 6 + 1 = 58$

Answer (score 1):

First we arrange the letters in alphabetical order. A,L,L,M,S
Now we find how many letters are coming before the word 'SMALL' through which we can find the rank of the word 'SMALL' by adding 1 to it.

Now there are $\frac{4!}{2!} $ of the type A_ _ _ _ (as we have to arrange L,L,M,S.)

Words of the type L_ _ _ _ = 4!(as we have to arrange A,L,M,S )

Words of the type M_ _ _ _ = $\frac{4!}{2!}$ ( as we have to arrange A,L,L,S)

Words of the type SA_ _ _ = $\frac{3!}{2!}$(as we have to arrange M,L,L )

Words of the type SL_ _ _ = 3! ( as we have to arrange A,M,L)

After these words the next word would be SMALL.

Adding we get , 57. therefore the rank of the world SMALL would be 57+1 = 58.

Another way of doing this sum.
Total no. of words formed by these letters would be $\frac{5!}{2!}$ = 60.The only words which occur after SMALL are SMLAL and SMLLA. From here we can easily say that rank of word SMALL is 58.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to work out the equation from the  front-down but what if instead of working out how many words are before of 'SMALL', you work out how many words are after it and subtract that from the total amount of words.

So the total amount of words is:

$\frac{5!}{2!} = 60$

as there are five letters and two duplicate letters.

and then for the amount of words after SMALL, well the 'S' and the 'M' are already in alphabetical order from least to greatest, and then nothing can come before 'A', so any combination of the last three letters will occur in the dictionary after the word 'SMALL'

so the number of words after it is:

$\frac{3!}{2!} - 1 = 2$

the one had to be taken, as the combinations includes the word 'SMALL' itself, which obviously can't appear after itself.

As @Henry said, only two words occur after 'SMALL', those words are:
'SMLAL', and 'SMLLA'.

So the word 'SMALL' is the third last word in this dictionary, so if you take the amount of words $60$ and minus $3$, than you get how many words are before it.

$60 - 3 = 57$

so 57 words occur before 'SMALL' and 'SMALL' is the 58th word in the dictionary.